# How do I extend the space of /dev/sda3 on Oracle Linux Server 7.9

Tags: linux, centos7, hard-drive, disk-space-utilization, oracle-linux

Disk capacity is at 105GB, but the root directory (/dev/sda3) capacity is only 39GB, I want to increase the capacity. How can we do this? By the way, the OS is Oracle Linux Server 7.9.

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs         11G     0   11G   0% /dev
tmpfs            11G     0   11G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            11G  115M   11G   2% /run
tmpfs            11G     0   11G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda3        39G   23G   17G  58% /
/dev/sda1       200M  7.9M  192M   4% /boot/efi
tmpfs           2.1G     0  2.1G   0% /run/user/0
tmpfs           2.1G     0  2.1G   0% /run/user/1000
tmpfs           2.1G     0  2.1G   0% /run/user/994

$ fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 105.2 GB, 105226698752 bytes, 205520896 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 1048576 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1    97677311    48838655+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Oracle Linux Server"
VERSION="7.9"
ID="ol"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VARIANT="Server"
VARIANT_ID="server"
VERSION_ID="7.9"
PRETTY_NAME="Oracle Linux Server 7.9"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:oracle:linux:7:9:server"
HOME_URL="https://linux.oracle.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.oracle.com/"

ORACLE_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Oracle Linux 7"
ORACLE_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.9
ORACLE_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Oracle Linux"
ORACLE_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.9
```

Comment: You cannot extend the size of `/dev/sda3` as it is a physical device. You can however add more storage to the machine and create a volume that can be expanded and then move the content of `/dev/sda3` to the newly created volume.

Comment: @LasseMichaelMølgaard
Thank you for your response.
By executing fdisk -l, it shows that my Disk capacity is 105GB, but I am currently using only 39GB, which means I can create at least a 65GB expandable volume, is that right? How should I do this?

Comment: Well if there is space left on the physical device (sda), then you could just use `resizefs /dev/sda3` to expand your volume.

Comment: I tried everything, but could not do it. I have a feeling I'm missing some steps.

```sh
    $ resize2fs /dev/sda3
    resize2fs 1.45.4 (23-Sep-2019)
    resize2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda3
    Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything, but could not do it. I have a feeling I'm missing some steps.

```
$ resize2fs /dev/sda3
resize2fs 1.45.4 (23-Sep-2019)
resize2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda3
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.

$ xfs_growfs /dev/sda3 -D size
meta-data=/dev/sda3              isize=256    agcount=4, agsize=2515200 blks
         =                       sectsz=4096  attr=2, projid32bit=1
         =                       crc=0        finobt=0, sparse=0, rmapbt=0
         =                       reflink=0
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=10060800, imaxpct=25
         =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0, ftype=1
log      =internal log           bsize=4096   blocks=4912, version=2
         =                       sectsz=4096  sunit=1 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0
data size unchanged, skipping



# df -hT
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs       devtmpfs   11G     0   11G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs      11G     0   11G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs      11G  115M   11G   2% /run
tmpfs          tmpfs      11G     0   11G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda3      xfs        39G   23G   17G  58% /
/dev/sda1      vfat      200M  7.9M  192M   4% /boot/efi
tmpfs          tmpfs     2.1G     0  2.1G   0% /run/user/0
tmpfs          tmpfs     2.1G     0  2.1G   0% /run/user/1000
tmpfs          tmpfs     2.1G     0  2.1G   0% /run/user/994
```

Comment: From your output it shows you are using `xfs` as filsystem. Searching online gave me that you cannot use `resize2fs`, but you should use `xfs_growfs` instead.

Comment: Thank you. However, I ran "xfs_growfs /dev/sda3 -D size" but the result was "data size unchanged, skipping".

Comment: @seiou, exec just `xfs_growfs /dev/sda3`